# How to enable or disable queue in Websphere application server

Tags: queue, jms, websphere

Iam using websphere application server and configured jms queues, which works fine. I have testing requirements to disable the queue and send the messages and after some time if I enable the queue those message to be process.  I have tried many website I cannot find the answer to how to do it.

Can help how to enable or disable jms queues in websphere application server ?

I have tried googling many website cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pause and resume the flow of messages from a JMS queue into WebSphere Application Server.  One way to do this is using mbean operations on the Message Endpoint as described in this [IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdat_msgendpoint.html).